# match pattern regex coldfusion

Tags: regex, coldfusion

i need to match  a pattern using `reMatchNoCase("(listid)","listid car van listid dog cat listid house hotel")>` so listid is the pattern and match that and everything to the next pattern witch is listid again.
so if i dump the rematch ill get a structure each starting with listid and the content within

this is what it should look like

1. listid car van
2. listid dog cat
3. listid house hotel

etc....

when i use `reMatchNoCase("(listid)","listid car van listid dog cat listid house hotel")>` it will only create a structure with "listid" and nothing more like car van... what regex do i use after (listid) to get everything within?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
listid.*?(?=(listid|$))
```

What this regex does is locate a 'listid' followed by any characters until next 'listid' or 'end of line ($)'. The `?=` is the positive lookahead to look for the next 'listid' but not make it part of the match. The `?` in `.*?` avoids greedy behavior of `.*` and matches immediate next lookahead string.

Comment: What do I need the $ newline for? Will it mess-up by a actual new line if I don't want it to??

Comment: Since there is no 'listid' at the end, we have to have something to look ahead for capturing the last match. Hence the use of '$'. If you remove it it will not match the 'listid house hotel' in your example.

Comment: And I dont know how it is exactly done in coldfusion, but generally languages provide a way to support regex in 'multiline' mode. You may try to find that out. Also regex has a modifier '/m' you can try to use if at all you face any problem

Comment: CF uses Apache ORO regex engine, which supports the `(?m)` inline modifier. Alternatively, just use `\z` instead of `$` to avoid worrying about newlines and only match at end of string.

Comment: Oh, and there's no need for the parentheses inside the lookahead.

Answer (score 2):

This regular expression will probably do; I don't know coldfusion details, but it matches what you want:

```
listid.*?(?=$|\slistid)
```